# Using a CSS File for site localization

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-2, localization, globalization

I'm creating a website with ASP.net MVC 2.0 which uses two different languages (English and Persian). I want to have two different layouts for these languages, English has a left to right and Persian has a right to left layout.

What came to my mind was, if I could have two different css files, like when you do it with string or image localization will do the work for the site, the problem is I need to know how to do this!

Any other suggestions on how to perform this would be helpful.

Comment: What exactly is your question - how to embed different style sheets according to language?

Comment: If the answer to @Pekka's question is yes, the next question you will need to answer is how is the selected language handled in your application?

Comment: Yeah I needed change the style sheet according to the language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can read about:

- [(W3C) Internationalization Best Practices: Specifying Language in XHTML & HTML Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-lang/),
- [Creating HTML Pages in Arabic, Hebrew and Other Right-to-left Scripts](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/),
- [Internationalization and localization (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization).

In your pages:

- every image with text should be translated (image and `alt`); every image with directionality should be reversed (ex: an arrow)
- try to avoid class naming like `class="left"` if you don't want future headaches. Top, bottom, before or after are OK but not left/right (edit: `start` and `end` are now used in CSS3 to avoid this exact problem of ltr and rtl. May be better than `*-before` and `*-after` already used for pseudos with colons).
- you'll have to check each CSS instruction about `text-align`, `background-position`, `float`, `clear` and obviously `left` and `right` with `position: absolute/relative;`. New CSS3 instructions are to review too (Animations, etc).
- different fonts need different font sizes (though this problem concerns asiatic fonts mainly)
- as for any other supported language, many bits of text in templates should be translated.

As noted in the links above, the HTML attribute `dir="rtl"` is used. You'll also need a class (on `body` or some containing `div` to act like a giant switch for your design needs. Like

```
.en .yourclass { background: url(images/en/bg.jpg) } 
.ar .yourclass { background: url(images/ar/bg.jpg) }
```

The attribute selector does the same, since IE8 included.

```
:lang(ar) .yourclass { background: url(images/ar/bg.jpg) }
or
[lang|="ar"] .yourclass { background: url(images/ar/bg.jpg) }
```

Comment: **:lang(ar) .yourclass** for work this, we need to set html attribute `lang="en"` or `lang="ar"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you can use to get the Locale at the client side. Once you have the locale defined, you can dynamically include a stylesheet in the header.

```
if ( navigator ) {
    if ( navigator.language ) {
        return navigator.language;
    }
    else if ( navigator.browserLanguage ) {
        return navigator.browserLanguage;
    }
    else if ( navigator.systemLanguage ) {
        return navigator.systemLanguage;
    }
    else if ( navigator.userLanguage ) {
        return navigator.userLanguage;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather do this in the server side language (ASP.NET in this case) based on HTTP [`Accept-Language`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) request header. I don't do ASP.NET, but as every other self-respected view technology it truly must have a way to determine that header and output the `<link>` to the CSS conditionally.

Comment: And how can I change the stylesheet in the header?

Comment: Well that's not the case I was looking for, I've been trying to do this in a resource file which is much more routine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you ar elooking for, but I did this a few years back in VBScript.  Not ideal, but it works for me:

Figure out the language:

```
<%
Dim sLanguage
sLanguage = Request.QueryString("lang")

Dim userLocale
userLocale=Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE")

Dim sDomain
sDomain = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")

Dim languages
languages = Split(userLocale, ",", -1)


...
```

Set the style sheet...

```
<% select case MasterLanguage
    case "PORTUGUESE"%>
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">@import "/Includes/css/a_formatting.css";</style>
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">@import "/includes/langs/br/languageSpecific.css";</style>
        <link type="text/css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" href="/Includes/css/print.css" />
<%
case "SIMPCHINESE"
%>
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">@import "/Includes/css/a_formatting_zh-cn.css";</style>
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">@import "/includes/langs/zh-cn/languageSpecific.css";</style>
        <link type="text/css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" href="/Includes/css/print_zh-cn.css" />
<%
```

I can post more snippets if this is helpful.