# One page html static mutlilanguage

Tags: html, css

I have a school assignment to create a one page `html` static.
I want to have some buttons to change the language but I don't want any addition like `"index.html/en/"` or `"index.html?lang=en"`. I prefer to have it with `CSS` only but I don't know whether it is possible or not.

In short I just want a simply bilingual `"index.html"` and have buttons to change the content text.

I am new in html scripting so I'm looking for some sample code or some detailed tutorial will be help.

Comment: then it will be a big file, ex: type hello in 5 div in 5 language and then on click of button show hide them..

Comment: Have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3313102/5580153    Edit: It's not going to be straight forward for you in a single-page document.

Comment: I don't mind for it to be a big file, how to hide/show that 5 div?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using JS/jQuery for that:

Have language mapping for each element that will be translated:

```js
// Translations object:
var translations = {
  'en': {
    'home': 'Home',
    'back': 'Back'
    /* ... */
  },
  'lt': {
    'home': 'Pradžia',
    'back': 'Atgal'
    /* ... */
  }
};


// wait for all DOM elements to load
$(document).ready(function() {

  // when button is clicked
  $('.lang-btn').click(function() {
    // take translations subset
    var lang = translations[$(this).data('lang')];

    // for each element that has "data-key" attribute
    $('[data-key]').each(function() {

      // change it's content to other language
      $(this).text(lang[$(this).data('key')]);
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-page">
  Language:
  <button class="lang-btn" data-lang="en">En</button>
  <button class="lang-btn" data-lang="lt">Lt</button>
  <hr/>
  <a href="home.html" data-key="home">Home</a>
  <button data-key="back">Back</button>
</div>
```

**This code is not checking if there is such translation or not. You can improve this algo with fallback to English.**

Answer (score 0):

For SEO reasons I'd prefer to use `/en/`. Use a `.htaccess` file with `mod_rewrite`.
See here [Create beautiful url’s with mod_rewrite](https://www.branded3.com/blog/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one page, so I assume the contain is not much. Try something simpler like:

```
function en() {
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "Example";
}
function de() {
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "Beispiel";
}
```

```
<div id="content">sample</div>
<button onclick="en()">English</button>
<button onclick="de()">German</button>
```